# CodeIgniter Controller - JSON - AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to send a form build with CodeIgniter via AJAX and trying to get the response with JSON. However, I only see the respond when I open my developer tab (I'm not even sure, if that's actually a respond since it's showing both of the json data's).

All it shows, is the loading spinner, and after that it vanishes.

Code have been tested without AJAX and it works, so there can't be errors in PHP.

Here's my controller for resetting the password:

```
<?php

Class Users extends CI_Controller {

    public function forgot_pass()
    {

    if(!$this->input->post('to_email'))
    {
    exit("No data");
    }


    $this->load->model('user');
    $email = $this->input->post('to_email');
    $email_addr = $this->user->get_email_address($email);


    if(empty($email_addr))
    {
    echo json_encode(array('pls'=>0, 'msg' => "E-mail address was not found. Try  again"));
    }

    $this->load->helper('string');
    $new_password = random_string('alnum', 8);
    $this->load->library('phpass'); 

    $update_password = array( 'password' => $this->phpass->hash($new_password));
    $update_password = $this->user->update_password($email, $update_password);

    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['newline'] = '\r\n';
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
    $this->email->to($email);  
    $this->email->subject('New password');
    $this->email->message("Hey, " .$email_addr['name']. ". Your new password is: " .$new_password); 

    if($this->email->send())
    {
    echo json_encode(array('pls'=>1, 'msg' => "Password has been sent to given e-mail address"));
    }


}

}
?>
```

And here's my AJAX call written with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("form#forget_pass_form").on('submit', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

                $("#loading_spinner").show();
                var from = $(this);

                $.ajax({

                    url: from.attr('action'),
                    type: from.attr('method'),
                    data: $(from).serialize(),
                    }).done(function(data) {



                    if(data.pls == 0) {

                        $("#forgot-pass-success").hide();
                        $("#forgot-pass-error").show();
                        $("#forgot-pass-error").fadeIn(1000).html(data.msg);

                      }

                    if(data.pls == 1) {

                        $("#forgot-pass-error").hide();
                        $("#forgot-pass-success").show();
                        $("#forgot-pass-success").fadeIn(1000).html(data.msg);
                      }

                   $("#loading_spinner").hide(); 

                });

            return false;

        });
});
```

Comment: in $.ajax `dataType` is missing please add dataType: 'JSON' in $.ajax call; also use use die or exit to stop the execution of the script

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, can you try setting the correct header in the Controller?

`header('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

Or better yet:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
```

As a side note, you should make sure you are always returning JSON data, so I would remove the `exit()` message and put a default JSON response at the bottom of the method.

Don't forget, when you echo your JSON, you can put `return;` afterwards to stop any more code running afterwards in that method.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick.. I figured it out like a minute ago. Thanks anyway. I'll mark this as a accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Most of your code is ok. But you need to change some lines, both in your js, and controller.

**Change 1(In Ajax function)**

Change your ajax function and add **`dataType: "json"`** option

```
    $.ajax({
           url: from.attr('action'),
           type: from.attr('method'),
           dataType: "json",
           data: $(from).serialize(),
          }).done(function(data) {

           ....

        });
```

**Change 2 (In controller)**

> exit("No data");

to

> exit(json_encode(array('pls'=>0, 'msg' => "No data")));

**Change 3 (In controller)**

> echo json_encode(array('pls'=>0, 'msg' => "E-mail address was not found. Try  again"));

to

> exit(json_encode(array('pls'=>0, 'msg' => "E-mail address was not found. Try  again")));

**explanation**

1. First change tell your script to handle the response data as Json
2. Second change is to keep all your return type same, if not when you sending only the **`no data`** response you are not handling this option from youe js.
3. And the last change make sure you stop further processing when sending email fails, and stop from showing both json.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you about json return. 
First in your ajax you have to  use `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax ({
        url: from.attr('action'),
        type: from.attr('method'),
        data: $(from).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data) {

           ..your code..

    });
```

CodeIgniter have `output` class, why don't you use `output` class to respond to ajax from `CI`.

```
$output = array('pls' => 1,
                'msg' => "Password has been sent to given e-mail address"
          );
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
             ->set_output(json_encode($output));
```

Use `output` class, this is more efficient then `echo`

I hope it will helps you for better code style.