# Populate five dropdowns (not dependent) in single Ajax call in Codeigniter

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

Framework - Codeigniter

I need to populate multiple drop down lists on view onload function. Currently I use five Ajax requests to populate five dropdowns. I think this is inefficient and will reduce my application performance and increase the bandwidth usage. Is there any efficient alternative way to do this? (like populate them all in single Ajax call)

In my View

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  
              

              {
            $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Pharmacy_elements/fetch_main_catagories",
              method:'get',
              headers: XMLHttpRequest + new Date().getTime(),
              
              success:function(data){
               
                $('#main_catagory').html(data);
           
              }
            })
    
    
        }

        {
            $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Pharmacy_elements/fetch_sub_catagories",
              method:'get',
              headers: XMLHttpRequest + new Date().getTime(),
              
              success:function(data){
               
                $('#sub_catagory').html(data);
           
              }
            })
    
    
        }

        {
            $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Pharmacy_elements/fetch_serving_types",
              method:'get',
              headers: XMLHttpRequest + new Date().getTime(),
              
              success:function(data){
               
                $('#common_serving_type').html(data);
           
              }
            })
    
    
        }

        {
            $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Pharmacy_elements/fetch_approved_suppliers",
              method:'get',
              headers: XMLHttpRequest + new Date().getTime(),
              
              success:function(data){
               
                $('#supplier_name').html(data);
           
              }
            })
    
    
        }


        })
```

My Controller

```
 public function fetch_mother_companies()
      {
            $output = '';
           
            $this->load->model('Pharmacy_model');
            $data = $this->Pharmacy_model->fetch_mother_companies();
        //    $output .='<option value=0>All</option>';
            if($data->num_rows()>0){
                  
                foreach($data->result() as $row){
                 
                        $output .='    
                                          <option value='.$row->id.'>'.$row->company_name.'</option>';
    
                        
                    }
                   }
                   else {               
                   }
                   
                   echo $output;
        }

public function fetch_main_catagories()
      {
            $output = '';
           
            $this->load->model('Pharmacy_model');
            $data = $this->Pharmacy_model->fetch_main_catagories();
        //    $output .='<option value=0>All</option>';
            if($data->num_rows()>0){
                  
                foreach($data->result() as $row){
                 
                        $output .='    
                                          <option value='.$row->id.'>'.$row->category_name.'</option>';
    
                        
                    }
                   }
                   else {               
                   }
                   
                   echo $output;
        }
        

   public function fetch_sub_catagories()
        {
              $output = '';
             
              $this->load->model('Pharmacy_model');
              $data = $this->Pharmacy_model->fetch_sub_catagories();
          //    $output .='<option value=0>All</option>';
              if($data->num_rows()>0){
                    
                  foreach($data->result() as $row){
                   
                          $output .='    
                                            <option value='.$row->category_id.'>'.$row->category_name.'</option>';
      
                          
                      }
                     }
                     else {               
                     }
                     
                     echo $output;
          }
```

Comment: Build one separate endpoint, from there rather than echoing html, you could return array as json. then in the javascript you could build the html and append it with the respective dropdown

Comment: please show with diagram .

Comment: @NULL - If so will it affect to the performance due to the client side JS rendering the DOM?

Comment: @KUMAR - Diagram means?

Comment: @TDJ picture format?

Comment: @NULL Please write it as answer what you mention it comment so future readers also learn.

Comment: @KUMAR I just pointing out the direction. 

TDJ it will be much faster then calling 5times.
this links might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123271/codeigniter-controller-json-ajax
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54534458/codeigniter-not-returning-json-ajax-response